# AWS S3 directory listing "?delimiter=/" issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am following the S3 directory listing using the code & following the steps mentioned here : https://github.com/rufuspollock/s3-bucket-listing (3. Use Amazon S3 in website mode with prefix mode) Error: [object Object]

The Chrome console shows
http://[bucket].s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?delimiter=/ 
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>S3 Bucket Listing Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navigation"></div>
  <div id="listing"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var S3BL_IGNORE_PATH = true;
   // var BUCKET_NAME = 'tests3kv';
    var BUCKET_URL = 'http://[bucket].s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
    //var S3B_ROOT_DIR = 'SUBDIR_L1/SUBDIR_L2/';
    var S3B_SORT = 'NEW2OLD';
    //var EXCLUDE_FILE = 'index.html';
    //var AUTO_TITLE = true;
    //var S3_REGION = 's3'; // for us-east-1
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/rufuspollock/s3-bucket-listing/gh-pages/list.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

i am invoking the site using http://[bucket].s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no REST endpoint in the `us-east-1` region supporting the format `https://bucketname.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.

The `us-east-1` region is the original S3 region and works differently than all the other regions in that regard.

Use one of these forms, instead:

```
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com
https://bucketname.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com
https://bucketname.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The last one supports both IPv4 and IPv6. Otherwise, these all function identically.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region